# Dynamic number of X values (dependent variables) in glm function in R isn't giving the right output

Tags: python, r, logistic-regression, glm, rpy2

R-glm for logistic regression. I was trying to dynamically input values to the formula according to another stack-overflow post.
The function is called from python using rpy2. when I printed out summery(glm.out).
I ran the test for 2 different scenarios.

- The input x,y values were taken directly from the python part of the code, and converted to the right format, and passed to logestic_regression function in R. The input value from python is printed below (2nd code block). glm is run on those values using as.formula. And this gave me an output (4th block of code)

  The input x,y values are just created in R as given in the code (in this case x=k1,k2 and y=m.) And glm function is run in the traditional way. And that gave me a different output (6th block of code)

The inputs are numerically correct. But the format is different. First scenario- a dataframe and Second- vectors.
Or my glm call is wrong.

R code.

```
logistic_regression = function(y,x,colnames){
    print("Y value is ")
    print(y)
    print("X value is ")
    print(x)
    m <- c(1,1,1,0,0,0)
    k1 <- c(4,3,5,1,2,3)
    k2 <- c(6,7,8,5,6,3)

    glm.out = glm(as.formula(paste("y~", paste(colnames, collapse="+"))), family=binomial(logit), data=x)
    # glm.out = glm(m~k1+k2, family=binomial(logit), data=x)    
    return(summary(glm.out))
}
```

INPUT PRINTED

```
[1] "Y value is "
[1] 1 1 1 0 0 0
[1] "X value is "
  X0 X1
0  4  6
1  3  7
2  5  8
3  1  5
4  2  6
5  3  3
```

When I ran the code

```
glm.out = glm(as.formula(paste("y~", paste(colnames, collapse="+"))), family=binomial(logit), data=x)
```

OUTPUT

```
Call:
glm(formula = as.formula(paste("y~", paste(colnames, collapse = "+"))), 
    family = binomial(logit), data = x)

Deviance Residuals: 
[1]  0  0  0  0  0  0

Coefficients: (3 not defined because of singularities)
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -2.457e+01  1.310e+05       0        1
X02          6.872e-14  1.853e+05       0        1
X03          3.566e-14  1.853e+05       0        1
X04          4.913e+01  1.853e+05       0        1
X05          4.913e+01  1.853e+05       0        1
X15                 NA         NA      NA       NA
X16                 NA         NA      NA       NA
X17          4.913e+01  1.853e+05       0        1
X18                 NA         NA      NA       NA

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 8.3178e+00  on 5  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2.5720e-10  on 0  degrees of freedom
AIC: 12

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 23
```

But when I ran

```
glm.out = glm(m~k1+k2, family=binomial(logit), data=x)
```

The output was completely different (looked more correct)

```
Call:
glm(formula = m ~ k1 + k2, family = binomial(logit), data = x)

Deviance Residuals: 
         0           1           2           3           4           5  
 1.532e-06   1.390e-05   2.110e-08  -2.110e-08  -1.344e-05  -2.110e-08  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)    -199.05 1221734.18       0        1
k1               25.30  281753.45       0        1
k2               20.89  288426.19       0        1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 8.3178e+00  on 5  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 3.7636e-10  on 3  degrees of freedom
AIC: 6

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 24
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `glm`, the `formula` argument is a symbolic description of the model to be fitted and the `data` argument is an optional data frame containing the variables in the model.

In your `logistic_regression` function call of `glm()`, the model variables indicated in formula `y~k1+k2` are not contained within `data=x` (a data frame with two columns named `X0` and `X1`), and thus, are taken from the environment from which glm is called (your `logistic_regression` function).  The 3 hardcoded vectors (`m, k1, k2`) in that environment are not associated with the inputs (i.e., the `x=k1,k2 and y=m` step done in your second scenario is not occurring within your function).

To call glm() using your `logistic_regression()` input, you could create a data frame consisting of the model variables to use as a single input and edit your function accordingly.  For example, you could use:

```
x <- data.frame(y=c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), k1=c(4,3,5,1,2,3), k2= c(6,7,8,5,6,3))

logistic_regression <- function(x){
  glm.out <- glm(as.formula(paste("y~", paste(colnames(x[,-1]), collapse="+"))), family=binomial(logit), data=x)
  return(summary(glm.out))
}

logistic_regression(x)
```